# React and React Router, rendering the same element twice with a different prop results in two elements with the same prop?

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, components, react-router

I'm trying to use React with React-router v4 to render a few elements.

The idea is that the component is a list of articles from a website, with each Route using a different API key to get articles from a different site.

I'm using a single component to display the articles, and with each Route I want to pass a different API key.

The issue I have is that each route is using the same API key, which is the key of the first Route visited.

The source code is below:

```js
var APIKeys = {
    BBCKey: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-sport&sortBy=top&apiKey=foo',
    ESPNKey: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=espn&sortBy=top&apiKey=foo',
    FourFourTwoKey: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=four-four-two&sortBy=top&apiKey=foo'
}

let App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="container">
      <header>
        <span className="icn-logo"><i className="material-icons">code</i></span>
        <ul className="main-nav">
          <li><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/BBCSport">BBC Sport</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/FourFourTwo">FourFourTwo</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/ESPN">ESPN</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/BBCSport" render={ () => <GetArticles APIKey={APIKeys.BBCKey} /> } />
        <Route path="/FourFourTwo" render={ () => <GetArticles APIKey={APIKeys.FourFourTwoKey} /> } />
        <Route path="/ESPN" render={ () => <GetArticles APIKey={APIKeys.ESPNKey} /> } />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ArticleList from './ArticleList';

export default class GetArticles extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articleTitles: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(this.props.APIKey)
      .then(response => {
        let titles = response.data.articles.map( (currentObj) => {
          return currentObj.title;
        } );

        this.setState({
          articleTitles: titles,
          loading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main-content">
          <h1 className="main-title">Articles</h1>
          { (this.state.loading) ? <p>Loading</p> :   <ArticleList list={this.state.articleTitles} /> }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

My two questions are, is this a good idea using a single component like this, even if it is rendering different information, or should I have a component that renders each different list of articles?

How can I fix it so the appropriate API key is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think reason is, `componentDidMount` will get called only ocne, just after the initial rendering, since you are using the same component for each route, so `componentDidMount` will not get called again. You need to use `componentwillreceiveprops` lifecycle method also, and check if you receive the new APIkey then do the api call inside that.

**[componentDidMount:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)**

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

**[componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)**:

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

Write the component like this:

```
export default class GetArticles extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articleTitles: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('initial rendering', this.props.APIKey)
    this._callApi(this.props.APIKey);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
     if(newProps.APIKey != this.props.APIKey){
        this._callApi(newProps.APIKey);
        console.log('second time rendering', newProps.APIKey)
     }
  }

  _callApi(APIKey){
    axios.get(APIKey)
      .then(response => {
        let titles = response.data.articles.map( (currentObj) => {
          return currentObj.title;
        } );

        this.setState({
          articleTitles: titles,
          loading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main-content">
          <h1 className="main-title">Articles</h1>
          { (this.state.loading) ? <p>Loading</p> :   <ArticleList list={this.state.articleTitles} /> }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought it would be something to do with the Lifecycle methods but this doesn't solve it, I'll keep playing around.

Comment: do one thing, put `console.log(this.props.APIKey)` inside render method and show the result of that when changing the route.

Comment: put the `console.log()` inside `componentDidMount` and `componentWillRecieveProps` method also and check they are getting on route change or not.

Comment: I've placed the console.log() in each of these methods. Inside the render() method it returns the correct API key, however none of the other console.logs() are outputted.

Comment: oh sorry, there was a spelling mistake in `componentWillReceiveProps` function try the updated code, and check the console log values, it should work :)

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly! Thank you for putting the time in to help me with this, for reference I tried using the componentWillUpdate() lifecycle method also which did make it work, except the virtual DOM switched between the old and new articles a few times before settling, which caused the content to updated on the screen repeatedly for a few seconds. Thanks for your help.