# React Router v4 - Switch doesn't work with route render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router to display the same component but with different props on each route:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => LOGGED_IN ? <Redirect to="/profile" /> : <Login />} />
    <Route path="/profile/:id" render={(props) => <App {...props} page="profile" pageLadder={['Home', 'Profile']} />}/>
    <Route path="/team" render={() => <App page="team" pageLadder={['Home', 'Team']} />}/>
    <Route path="/transactions" render={() => <App page="transactions" pageLadder={['Home', 'Transactions']} />}/>
    <Route path="/tournaments" render={() => <App page="tournaments" pageLadder={['Home', 'Tournaments']} />}/>
    <Route path="/tournament/:id" render={(props) => <App {...props} page="tournament" pageLadder={['Home', 'Tournament', props.match.params.id]} />}/>
    <Route path="/match/:id" render={(props) => <App {...props} page="match" pageLadder={['Home', 'Match', props.match.params.id]} />} />
    <Route path="/scrims" render={() => <App page="scrims" pageLadder={['Home', 'Scrims']} />} />
    <Route path="/faq" render={() => <App page="faq" pageLadder={['Home', 'FAQ']} />} />
    <Route path="/staff" render={() => <App page="staff" pageLadder={['Home', 'Staff']} />} />
    <Route path="/privacy" render={() => <App page="privacy" pageLadder={['Home', 'Privacy Policy']} />} />
    <Route path="/tos" render={() => <App page="tos" pageLadder={['Home', 'Terms of Service']} />} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I also need to catch 404 errors, so I added `Switch` and `<Route component={NotFound} />`:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => LOGGED_IN ? <Redirect to="/profile" /> : <Login />} />
    ... more routes
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The 404 does work, but every `<Link>` element kind of stops working - after clicked, the url does change but the component stays the same, unless I refresh the site.

I tried changing my code to this to test:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/team" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/profile/" component={App} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

With this code the `<Link>` component does work as intended.

What can I do to make my first code work as intended?

Comment: do you use `react-redux`?

Comment: @Sagivb.g No, I don't.

Comment: From your description, sounds like the issue is in the `<App />` component. Sounds like you have some conditional rendering logic based off of `this.props.page`? My guess is that something is blocking the render or you are not updating it correctly. Can you post the code for your `<App/>` component as well?

Comment: then are you implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` somewhere in the tree?

Comment: possible duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008510/react-and-react-router-rendering-the-same-element-twice-with-a-different-prop-r
did you check this ?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda The `<App />` component just puts the other components together, but I made a simplified version here: https://pastebin.com/raw/mbZ6Lcpy

Comment: @theneuetimes Yes, I see the problem. Working on an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code example:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    // appStore is an instance of react-easy-state library
    // App component puts the components together, the actual pages are in AppMain component (look below for code)
    appStore.changePage(this.props.page, this.props.pageLadder, this.props.match ? this.props.match.params.id : -1);
    // this function changes appStore.page.name value and it's a global type store
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Sidebar />
          <AppMain />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You are calling `appStore.changePage` in the **constructor**, which only get's called one time, when the component is first initialized. Even though you have the  component on several routes, it's not getting unmounted when you change the route and props, meaning that the constructor is never getting called again.

What you need to do is use `componentDidUpdate` to change the page when your **props** change:

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevProps.page !== this.props.page) {
    appStore.changePage(this.props.page, this.props.pageLadder, this.props.match ? this.props.match.params.id : -1);
  }
}
```

Now, you compare the `prevProps` from the current props and if the `page` prop has changed, you need to trigger `appStore.changePage` again. Now, I'm not sure what `appStore.changePage` is doing so I'm not sure if you'll need to update `<AppMain />` as well, but this should get you on the right track.